# How to grab and display img from external site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to grab the image from an external site, in my case, [http://bikerace.com/tracks/[levelCode]](http://bikerace.com/tracks/%5blevelCode%5d)
(as an example level code, nhx874, the url would be http://www.bikerace.com/tracks/nhx874)

Users on bikeracelevels(dot com) have to input the level code THEN upload a screenshot. I'm trying to remove this requirement by automatically grabbing the image based on the code they input, since I could append their input code to the url, then somehow find the image (since the only image on the page would be the one I want)

How could I accomplish this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: That doesn't seem like an image, but rather a swf file - or am I not seeing this correctly?

Comment: The main window is flash, yes, but there's an image at the top left of the page, which is what I would like to grab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get this cross-domain AJAX plugin for use with jQuery: https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax

Use it to load the page on bikerace.com/[levelcode], then select the image from the data as you normally would with jQuery.

Comment: That seems PERFECT! Now I just hope I can figure out how to implement it. I would up vote your answer, but I'm not cool enough yet. Thanks

Comment: @Nick Don't be afraid to come back and ask a new question when you get stuck with something. **Do** realize that the question you just posted is normally not of sufficient quality here. You need to have tried something already and at least post some code and a specific thing you can't nail. Good luck, and welcome to StackOverflow.